# Twitter search for images from user

Tags: twitter, twitter-search-2

I want to use the twitter user api to get all images from a user. 
I have tried using search, but sadly the search api only has 6-9 days worth of tweets. (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search)

Is there anything that will filter tweets with an image and give me the direct link to the image? If not I will have to write it myself. 
I am currently using EE Twitter by Click Rain to get all tweets from a user.

Comment: This question would probably be best asked directly to the developers of the Twitter search add-ons found on devot-ee.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coming back way later, but good job adding this functionality to [EE Twitter](http://github.com/click-rain/EE_Twitter). And many thanks. The beauty of open source, eh?